# How can I remove inner text between all <script>..</script/> by a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regular expressions, to remove all the content between two strings ...

Suppose this is my content:

```
    <h2>Misrepresentation of the Facts</h2>
    </script>
    <!-- Articles - Leaderboard 728x90 -->
    </iframe></ins></ins></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    <h2>Who Can Commit the Crime</h2>

    I want to remove all content between </script>
    <!-- Articles - Leaderboard 728x90 -->
    </iframe></ins></ins></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
<\/script>(?:[^<]*(?!.)+<\/script>

<\/script>(?:[^<]*(?!.)+<\/script>
```

Comment: Please, re-format your question so that it would be visible where's code and where's the text. Thanks.

Comment: You need more information about the construction of these files to be able to answer your question correctly. If your code contains more <script> </ script> tags than you have shown in the example, a simple regex may also corrupt the correct code. Perhaps it's better to use a different approach but we do not know enough about the problem.

Comment: Remove all invisible content `<(?:(script|style|object|embed|applet|noframes|noscript|noembed)(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>)[\S\s]*?</\1\s*>`

Comment: I've edited your title, but the body of your question is still inconsistent about `<script>` vs. `</script>`. It makes sense to want to delete everything starting with `<script>` and `</script>`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Are you able to assume that the `<script>` and `</script>` tags never nest, and that they never appear in comments or string literals (where they presumably would be ignored)? If not, then [this famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/827263) has some things to say about parsing HTML with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing that these expressions being replaced by an empty string might work:

```
<\/script>[\s\S]*?<\/script>
<\/script>[\d\D]*?<\/script>
<\/script>[\w\W]*?<\/script>
```

[Please see the demo here](https://regex101.com/r/duwAOK/1/).

Escaping is just for demoing, and can be removed.

Comment: "<script>[^<]*<\/script> " -This script  working but not cover all text which i want to remove and "<\/script>.*?<\/script>" this is not working..

Comment: <h2>Misrepresentation of the Facts</h2>
</script>
<!-- Articles - Leaderboard 728x90 -->
</iframe></ins></ins></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
<h2>Who Can Commit the Crime</h2>                                                                                                The above all text i want to remove  all text between </script>...</script>                  i only need <h2>Misrepresentation of the Facts</h2>  <h2>Who Can Commit the Crime</h2>

Comment: yes almost but my text is too long and not selected all items "<h2>Misrepresentation of the Facts</h2>Mortgage fraud .<br><br>
</script>
<!-- Articles - Leaderboard 728x90 -->
</iframe></ins></ins></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
<h2>Who Can Commit the Crime</h2>While the general person that commits mortgageg, th<br><h2>Committing Mortgage Fraud</h2>Those acting ent laws.<br><h2>Criminal Defense for Mortgage Fraud</h2>When facing charges for mortgage frau

"

Comment: i want to remove all text which come in between the text "</script>
<!-- Articles - Leaderboard 728x90 -->
</iframe></ins></ins></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>"    alll i want remove

Comment: oo Great finally working this which i want to remove thanks a lot bro i tried since yesterday.I am using ubot tools for scraping data and remove add from that scraped data.